# magento accesing "SendFriend" module from category page

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add the "send to a friend" action to a category page.

In the product view i can see this code:
"canEmailToFriend()): ?>

```
   <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

If I try to add this code to my "list.phtml" (where products grid is displayed) I receive this error: 
    Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::canEmailToFriend(Array

saying that this methos is not available in this context...

Who can I add the funcionality of "sendtofriend" module to any page I need?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `$this->canEmailToFriend()` call is a block method belonging to the product page, a class called `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`.  The product listing page uses a block class called `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` which does not include this code.

The method `canEmailToFriend()` contains (as defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php`) the logic:

```
$sendToFriendModel = Mage::registry('send_to_friend_model');
return $sendToFriendModel && $sendToFriendModel->canEmailToFriend();
```

You *could* embed that directly in your template and then call the helper to output the link if `$sendToFriendModel->canEmailToFriend()`, but the best way to achieve this would be to move the `canEmailToFriend` functionality out into a new helper and call it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I founded an alternative solution, just load `sendfriend` model

```
$sendToFriendModel = Mage::getModel('sendfriend/sendfriend');
```

Then use

```
<?php if ( $sendToFriendModel->canEmailToFriend() ) : ?>
    <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></span></span></a></p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Resource from  [C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/controllers/ProductController.php](http://freegento.com/doc/d5/d5e/_catalog_2_block_2_product_2_view_8php-source.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think `Mage::registry('send_to_friend_model')` returns an object of the class `Mage_Sendfriend_Model_Sendfriend`. The `canEmailToFriend()` method in `Mage_Sendfriend_Model_Sendfriend` checks whether the "email to a friend" functionality is enabled:

You can find these two methods in `app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Model/Sendfriend.php`:

```
/**
 * Check if user is allowed to email product to a friend
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function canEmailToFriend()
{
    return $this->_getHelper()->isEnabled();
}

/**
 * Retrieve Data Helper
 *
 * @return Mage_Sendfriend_Helper_Data
 */
 protected function _getHelper()
 {
     return Mage::helper('sendfriend');
 }
```

So you could check that yourself in your template like so:

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('sendfriend')->isEnabled()) : ?>
    <?php // Do stuff ?>
<?php endif ?>
```